# Send Instapaper articles to free.kindle address

Tags: kindle, instapaper

Is there a way to send articles to my Kindle from Instapaper using the `username@free.kindle.com` address?

I don't need the articles delivered over 3G, but would prefer to have them delivered over Wi-Fi instead of having to do the manual download, load to Calibre, then sync with Kindle dance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Login into Instapaper, click on the "Account" link and then on "Manage my Kindle Settings". There, just follow the istructions

Comment: It appears that this setting is only there once you are an Instapaper subscriber. I subscribed and now I see the option to send to the @free.kindle.com address.